# Firebase push notifications are not working in Ionic

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, ionic3, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building an Ionic Progressive web application and integrating the Firebase push notification. I have done with everything but I am not getting the notification. I am following the solution given by : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48699547/2455259

My firebase-messaging.ts is:

```
   import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { FirebaseApp } from 'angularfire2';
// I am importing simple ionic storage (local one), in prod this should be remote storage of some sort.
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseMessagingProvider {
  private messaging;
  private unsubscribeOnTokenRefresh = () => {};

  constructor(
    private storage: Storage,
    private app: FirebaseApp
  ) {
    this.messaging = app.messaging();
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then((registration) => {
    this.messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);
    //this.disableNotifications()
    this.enableNotifications();
});
  }

  public enableNotifications() {
    console.log('Requesting permission...');
    return this.messaging.requestPermission().then(() => {
        console.log('Permission granted');
        // token might change - we need to listen for changes to it and update it
        this.setupOnTokenRefresh();
        return this.updateToken();
      });
  }

  public disableNotifications() {
    this.unsubscribeOnTokenRefresh();
    this.unsubscribeOnTokenRefresh = () => {};
    return this.storage.set('fcmToken','').then();
  }

  private updateToken() {
    return this.messaging.getToken().then((currentToken) => {
        console.log("heyyyyyy");
      if (currentToken) {
        // we've got the token from Firebase, now let's store it in the database
        console.log(currentToken)
        return this.storage.set('fcmToken', currentToken);
      } else {
        console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
      }
    });
  }

  private setupOnTokenRefresh(): void {
    this.unsubscribeOnTokenRefresh = this.messaging.onTokenRefresh(() => {
      console.log("Token refreshed");
      this.storage.set('fcmToken','').then(() => { this.updateToken(); });
    });
  }

}
```

My service-worker is:

```
/**
 * Check out https://googlechromelabs.github.io/sw-toolbox/ for
 * more info on how to use sw-toolbox to custom configure your service worker.
 */


'use strict';
importScripts('./build/sw-toolbox.js');'
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase-messaging.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase.js');


firebase.initializeApp({
  // get this from Firebase console, Cloud messaging section
  'messagingSenderId': '' 
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('Received background message ', payload);
  console.log("Service worker");
  const notificationOptions = {
    icon: '/assets/imgs/logo.png'
  };
  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});


self.toolbox.options.cache = {
  name: 'ionic-cache'
};

// pre-cache our key assets
self.toolbox.precache(
  [
    './build/main.js',
    './build/vendor.js',
    './build/main.css',
    './build/polyfills.js',
    'index.html',
    'manifest.json'
  ]
);

// dynamically cache any other local assets
self.toolbox.router.any('/*', self.toolbox.fastest);

// for any other requests go to the network, cache,
// and then only use that cached resource if your user goes offline
self.toolbox.router.default = self.toolbox.networkFirst;
```

App.module.ts is:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {YoutubePlayerModule} from 'ngx-youtube-player';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { HelloIonicPage } from '../pages/hello-ionic/hello-ionic';
import { ItemDetailsPage } from '../pages/item-details/item-details';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
import { FeaturedPage } from '../pages/featured/featured';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { ApiProvider } from '../providers/api/api';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {LatestPage} from '../pages/latest/latest';
import {TopPage} from '../pages/top/top';
import { TrendingPage } from '../pages/trending/trending';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/messaging'; // only import firebase messaging or as needed;
import { firebaseConfig } from '../environment';
import { FirebaseMessagingProvider } from '../providers/firebase-messaging';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,HelloIonicPage,ItemDetailsPage,ListPage,FeaturedPage,LatestPage,TopPage,TrendingPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,HttpClientModule,YoutubePlayerModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,HelloIonicPage,ItemDetailsPage,ListPage,FeaturedPage,LatestPage,TopPage,TrendingPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    ApiProvider,FirebaseMessagingProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

environment.ts is:

```
export const firebaseConfig = {
     apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
}
```

Index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Beauty of soul</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps (remove if not needed) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));

    }
  </script>

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
       It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

My project structure is:
[image]

Is there anything that I am missing? Even I am not getting the pop up that will ask the user if they are allowing to show the notifications or not. Please guide me.

Comment: Do you get any errors in console log? Which versions of firebase you are using?

Comment: In that issue I mentioned which specific versions of firebase I was using and I do recall my solution did not work with newest versions. So check which one you are using. I am planning to investigate and try to make this same code to work with the latest versions later this week and I will update the issue accordingly

Comment: Hi, I am using Firebase version - 4.9.0

Comment: Can I ask you if there is anything that I need to do in app.component.ts or the code that you gave in that answer is enough to implement the Push notifications in Ionic.

Comment: so in case of my app exactly that code is working for Android and as PWA on Android (Chrome). With iOS (since Safari mobile only starts to support certain features like service workers - I have not yet tested the whole thing)

Comment: but I am not even getting the prompt in which the user can give the permission of showing the notifications.

Comment: So if you followed my other issue's guidance - where is in your code these lines: navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then((registration) => {
    this.messaging.useServiceWorker(registration); }. See in my guidance that is inside firebase-messaging.ts provider. Yours doesn't have those. Did you really follow through my code precisely or if there is a reason why you have different code?

Comment: yes, I had removed these line because I was getting errors of Mime type. You can have a look on my another question, (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022518/refused-to-execute-script-in-ionic-pwa/51023923#51023923) . When I removed these lines then It was working fine. I thought, If I have registered this service worker in `index.html` then I could remove it from here. However, I have handled that error of Mime type and Now I put these lines in my code then also it is not working.  I am updating my question too.

Answer (score 0):

go to browser setting first then delete notification of your application then run once.